# Concatenate in bash the output of two commands without newline character

Tags: regex, bash, sed, pipe, concatenation

**What I need:**

Suppose I have two commands, `A` and `B`, each of which returns a single-line string (i.e., a string with no newline character, except possibly 1 at the very end).  I need a command (or sequence of piped commands) `C` that concatenates the output of commands `A` and `B` on the same line and inserts 1 space character between them.

**Example of how it should work:**

For example, suppose the output of command `A` is the string *between* the quotation marks here:

```
"The quick"
```

And suppose the output of command `B` is the string *between* the quotation marks here:

```
"brown fox"
```

Then I want the output of command(s) `C` to be the string *between* the quotation marks here:

```
"The quick brown fox"
```

**My best attempted solution:**

In trying to figure out `C` by myself, it seemed that the follow sequence of piped commands should work:

```
{ echo "The quick" ; echo "brown fox" ; } | xargs -I{} echo {} | sed 's/\n//'
```

Unfortunately, the output of this command is

```
The quick
brown fox
```

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You can use `tr`:

```
{ echo "The quick"; echo "brown fox"; } | tr "\n" " "
```

OR using sed:

```
{ echo "The quick"; echo "brown fox"; } | sed ':a;N;s/\n/ /;ba'
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
The quick brown fox
```

Comment: Thanks.  Why doesn't `sed 's/\n//'` work in place of the `tr` command?

Comment: @anubhava sed version does not work when there is more than two newlines, e.g. `{ echo "The quick"; echo "brown fox"; echo "something"; echo "else"; echo "more"; } | sed -e 'N;s/\n/ /'`

Comment: You can use a loop for that: `{ echo "The quick"; echo "brown fox"; echo "something"; echo "else"; echo "more"; } | sed ':a;N;s/\n/ /;ba'`

Answer (score 54):

```
echo "$(A)" "$(B)"
```

should work assuming that neither `A` nor `B` output multiple lines.

```
$ echo "$(echo "The quick")" "$(echo "brown fox")"
The quick brown fox
```

Comment: This answer is correct but proper quoting is required. ``echo "$(A)" "$(B)"`` and ``echo "$(echo "I love this asterisk sign")" "$(echo "*")"``. You can try it without quotes to see the problem

Comment: what about multiple lines case ?

Comment: By wrapping the two commands in a single pair of quotes you choose to have one, several, or no spaces between the outputs, like `echo "$(A) $(B)"`.

Answer (score 14):

I'll try to explain the solution with another simple example

We've to concatenate the output of the following command:
"pwd" and "ls"

```
echo "$(pwd)$(ls)";
```

Output: 2 concatenated strings

Answer (score 11):

```
$ commandA () { echo "The quick"; }
$ commandB () { echo "brown fox"; }
$ x="$(commandA) $(commandB)"
$ echo "$x"
The quick brown fox
```

Comment: This is the answer that worked for me. All the other ones did not. I just wanted to get the output of sensors on one line with a body of text I inserted with echo.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ { echo -n "The quick" ; echo -n " " ; echo "brown fox" ; }
The quick brown fox
```