# output two commands on same line

Tags: bash, sed, echo, concatenation

I have seen this question a few times, but the solutions I cannot get to work.

I have the following command:

```
printf '%s\n' "${fa[@]}" | xargs -n 3 bash -c 'cat *-$2.ss | sed -n 11,1p ; echo $0 $1 $2;'
```

where

```
printf '%s\n' "${fa[@]}"

O00238 115 03
O00238 126 04
```

and `cat *-$2.ss` gives:

```
   1 D C   0.999  0.000  0.000
   2 L C   0.940  0.034  0.012
   3 H C   0.971  0.005  0.015
   4 P C   0.977  0.005  0.009
   5 T C   0.970  0.009  0.018
   6 L C   0.977  0.006  0.011
   7 P C   0.864  0.027  0.014
   8 P C   0.966  0.018  0.011
   9 L C   0.920  0.038  0.039
  10 K C   0.924  0.043  0.039
  11 D C   0.935  0.036  0.035
  12 R C   0.934  0.023  0.053
  13 D C   0.932  0.022  0.046
  14 F C   0.878  0.041  0.088
  15 V C   0.805  0.031  0.198
  16 D C   0.834  0.039  0.108
  17 G C   0.882  0.019  0.071
  18 P C   0.800  0.031  0.132
  19 I C   0.893  0.039  0.070
  20 H C   0.823  0.024  0.179
  21 H C   0.920  0.026  0.070
  22 R C   0.996  0.001  0.002
```

running the command then produces

```
  11 D C   0.935  0.036  0.035
O00238 115 03
  11 K C   0.449  0.252  0.270
O00238 126 04
```

Even lines are the output of `sed -n 11,1p`, odd lines the output of echo `$0 $1 $2`

How do I pair the output on the same line i.e.

```
  11 D C   0.935  0.036  0.035 O00238 115 03
  11 K C   0.449  0.252  0.270 O00238 126 04
```

I have tried:

```
printf '%s\n' "${fa[@]}" | xargs -n 3 bash -c 'cat *-$2.ss | {sed -n 11,1p ; echo $0 $1 $2;} | tr "\n" " "'
```

as suggested here: [Concatenate in bash the output of two commands without newline character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20871534/concatenate-in-bash-the-output-of-two-commands-without-newline-character)

however I get

```
O00238: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
O00238: -c: line 0: `cat *-$2.ss | {sed -n 11,1p ; echo $0 $1 $2;} | tr "\n" " "'
```

What is the problem?

Comment: What is in the original array? Perhaps it'd be best to start from there, rather than picking through the pipeline you already have.

Comment: Instead of people trying to bolt something onto the end of your command,if you provide us with the original input and expected output then i think this can all be done in a single command.

Comment: thanks both - have added output of `printf '%s\n' "${fa[@]}"`

Comment: @brucezepplin we would also need to know what is in all the files in `*-$2.ss` (or an example of what would be in there)

Comment: thanks JID - have added output of `cat *-2.ss`

Comment: Where's the `11 K C` line in the output of `cat`?

Comment: @ Tom - each call to cat finds a different file. JID asked for an example - the one I give refers to the first line i.e. `11 D C   0.935  0.036  0.035 O00238 115 03`

Comment: So it's the 11th line of each of the files, right?

Comment: this could all be done in one simple, clear awk command but I see you've already selected an answer that adds more complexity to your pipeline so if you'd like to see how to do it all at once post a followup question.

Comment: hi Ed - I'm open to any solution really. It's only that I was already trying to do it in bash only and I can only choose one answer to accept. It may be helpful for others as well to see an awk solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not reproduce your setup, but

```
printf "O00238 115 03\nO00238 126 04" | xargs -n 3 bash -c 'cat test.dat | sed -n 11,1p | tr -d "\n"; echo " $0 $1 $2"'
```

gives

```
11 D C   0.935  0.036  0.035 O00238 115 03
11 D C   0.935  0.036  0.035 O00238 126 04
```

which should work in your case. I just deleted the newline of the sed command.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using something like this:

```
i=0
for f in *-"$2".ss; do printf '%s %s\n' "$(sed -n '11p' "$f")" "${fa[$((i++))]}"; done
```

This loops through your files and prints the 11th line alongside a slice from the array `fa`, whose index `i` increases by 1 every iteration.

Comment: @brucezepplin It's also shorter and more efficient!