# Concatenate file output text with Crontab

Tags: linux, cron, concatenation, cat, cron-task

I have followed up this question successfully, [Using CRON jobs to visit url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13259530/using-cron-jobs-to-visit-url), to maintain the following Cron task:

```
*/30 * * * * wget -O - https://example.com/operation/lazy-actions?lt=SOME_ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE >/dev/null 2>&1
```

The above Cron task works fine and it visits the URL periodically every 30 minutes.

However, the access token is recorded in a text file found in `/home/myaccount/www/site/aToken.txt`, the `aToken` file is very simple text file of one line which just contains the token string.

I have tried to read its contents and pass, using `cat`, it to the crontab command like the following:

```
*/30 * * * * wget -O - https://example.com/operation/lazy-actions?lt=|cat /home/myaccount/www/site/aToken.txt| >/dev/null 2>&1
```

However, the above solution has been failed to run the cronjob.

I edit Cronjobs using `crontab -e` using nano on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Since you have the access token stored in a physical file in your userfile .. Can't you just create a bash, or shell script that simply does everything you want it to do? IE open the token file, save to variable, wget website, write success / error logs etc etc etc ?

Comment: @Zak I'm not expert in bash and shell, and I had tried to keep things simple and clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Built on that question, [Concatenate in bash the output of two commands without newline character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20871534/concatenate-in-bash-the-output-of-two-commands-without-newline-character), I have got the following simple solution:

```
wget -O - https://example.com/operation/lazy-actions?lt="$(cat /home/myaccount/www/site/aToken.txt)" >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Where it able to read the contents of the text file and then echoed to the command stream.

Answer (score 1):

This is a quick solution that will do exactly what you want without the complicated one-liner:

Create this file in your `myaccount` --  You may also put it into your `bin` directory if you so desire just remember where you put it so you can call it from your `CRON`.  Also make sure the user has permissions to read/write to the directory the `sh` file is in

**wget.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

#simple cd -- change directory
cd /home/myaccount/www/site/  

#grab token into variable aToken
aToken=`cat aToken.txt`  

#simple cd -- move to wget directory
cd /wherever/you/want/the/wget/results/saved 

#Notice the $ -- This is how we let the shell know that aToken is a variable = $aToken
#wget -O - https://example.com/operation/lazy-actions?lt=$aToken
wget -q -nv -O /tmp/wget.txt https://example.com/operation/lazy-actions?lt=$aToken >/dev/null 2>/dev/null

# You can writle logs etc etc afterward here.  IE
echo "Job was successful" >> /dir/to/logs/success.log
```

Then simply call this file with your `CRON` like you are doing already.

```
*/30 * * * * sh /home/myaccount/www/site/wget.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: It looks like nice solution. However, I would not like any output from `wget` as shown in the cron job.

Comment: I've edited the wget inside to store the info in a temp file, then the dev/null should remove the temp file ..   --   You should be left with a clean wget after that ..

Comment: and if that doesn't work -- `--quiet` instead of `-q` may work depending on your setup ..

Comment: Thank you @Zak very much for your help, but I have found the solution that I, exactly, need.